# I am using OG module at Drupal 8. How to add role and role's permission for particular group here?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, organic-groups

I am using OG module at Drupal 8. How to add roles and role's permission  for particular group  here ??
I got OG roles overview(admin/config/group/roles) and OG permissions overview(admin/config/group/permissions) page at drupal 8. But When I click on edit section , it is displaying error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think , this section is still not develop . Is there any alternative way ??

Is there any way to create Roles and permission programmatically for OG ?? I am using 8.x-1.0-alpha4 OG module in Drupal 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group roles and permissions UI is still under development.

See https://github.com/Gizra/og/pull/243

Comment: When they will release it ?